# Using split in Java

Tags: java, split, analyzer, lexical

I am implementing a lexical analyzer using Java. 
Inside "String palavras_reservadas" I have all the reserved words that can't be used to name variables and stuff like that.
Matcher is responsible for finding those reserved word inside my input code.
I put all the lines from my input code in a different position of an ArrayList called "vetor1".
I want to split this "vetor1" when I find one reserved word. For example, i have this code as my input:

```
a = b + c;
if (a > b)
c = c + b;
```

My code will put each line in a different position of an array:

```
v[0] = a = b + c;
v[1] = if (a > b)
v[2] = c = c + b;
```

And what I want to do is:

```
v[0] = a = b + c;
v[1] = if 
v[2] = (a > b)
v[3] = c = c + b;
```

(Or something like that). Can I use split to do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
public class AnalisadorLexico { 
     public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

         List<String> vetor1 = new ArrayList<String>();
         File text = new File("/Users/Mvaguimaraes/Desktop/codigo.marcos");
         Scanner scnr = new Scanner(text);

         String palavras_reservadas = "fim-se|enquanto|então|se|senão|para|de|até|faça|fim-para|fim-enquanto";
         Pattern r = Pattern.compile(palavras_reservadas);
         int i = 0;
            while(scnr.hasNextLine())
            {

                String line = scnr.nextLine();
                vetor1.add(line);
                Matcher m = r.matcher(scnr.nextLine());
                if (m.find( )) {
                   System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group());

                }

            }  

                for(i = 0; i<vetor1.size(); i++)
                {
                        String value = vetor1.get(i);
                        System.out.println(value);
                }


        }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to use split you should have a char to split the sequence, for example 
    "if!(a>b)".split("!") 
gives you "if" and "(a>b)", not quite the case then i'm afraid

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without using split?

Comment: you can do it by checking for keywords (like if) using regex or by string.substring(0,3).equals("if") and then split them manually with substring like this: given your position in the list is k you do list.set(k,string.substring(0,3)) and list.add(k+1,string.substring(3,string.length)

Comment: In "m.group()" I have the string to split the sequence. So, how to I use it to split vetor1 in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `Pattern` class, for example

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(if) ([(].*[)])\n"));
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("if (a>b)");
if (matcher.matches()) {
  matcher.group(1); // "if"
  matcher.group(2); // "(a>b)"
}
```

Basically content in each parenthesis pair can be captured by group(k) method, where k is the kith parenthesis pair from the left. For details see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html